# Is it possible to group API operations by assemblies rather than controllers using NSwag in the Swagger UI?

Tags: nswag

I would like to group all API calls originating from an assembly to display together on the Swagger UI but see the grouping occurs at the controller by default. Any way to force the grouping to be at the assembly level? I am using NSwag to generate the Swagger UI.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement and add a custom operation processor which removes all tags and add a new one based on the assembly:

https://github.com/RSuter/NSwag/wiki/Document-Processors-and-Operation-Processors